# invalid key hash - android facebook

Tags: android, facebook, hash, google-play, release

I've created an app which uses the facebook login. I've added the key hash to the facebook developer page and it worked fine in all devices.
Now I've uploaded the app to google play, and when I try to login, it sais that the key hash does not match any stored key hashes.
I copied the key hash in the error message and pasted it. Still - doesn't work.
I tried to generate a key hash in cmd using the release key store - no luck.

Does anyone know what is the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following code snippet to your app while it's signed with the release certificate, compare the hash output with the one you submitted to the Facebook portal:

```
PackageInfo info;
try {
    info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.package.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        String hash= new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
        Log.e("hash", hash);
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
    Log.e("name not found", e1.toString());
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exception", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: But this gives me a key hash for debug. It is already in the Facebook portal. It is different from the key in the error message.

Comment: Publish you app with the release certificate and run the snippet, it will display the hash of the release certificate

Comment: If I try to run the app through android studio, it uses the debug keystore (it uninstall my app from google play and install a new one). If I run the app from google play, where will I see the log message?

Comment: No you won't. You need to add the code snippet to you project, publish a new apk with the release certificate, copy the APK to you device and install it. then connect your phone to your computer, run the app and check the log output

Comment: works! The problem was that when I copied the key hash to facebook portal, I wrote the letter I (i) instead of l (L)

Comment: great, I'm glad to hear that, please accept the answer if it helped.